# Internal Server Error Apache and WSGI (With Flask)

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi, wsgi, internal-server-error

(sorry fist question and not yet answered anything, I'll get to it!)

I am trying to setup Flask with Apache2 and mod_wsgi in an ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine, mainly so that I know how to do it in the future when I come to deploying a Flask application. Just so that you guys know, I am new to Python and Flask, but I am familiar with PHP, and as a consequence general programming practices.

I am following [this tutorial](https://beagle.whoi.edu/redmine/projects/ibt/wiki/Deploying_Flask_Apps_with_Apache_and_Mod_WSGI) to setup Flask. I have successfully setup the test application defined in the tutorial, however when I try to setup an existing application using the tutorial I get the following error:

```
Internal Server Error
    The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.     
    Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

Here is my app.py file, I suspect there is an error here but I can't find it, I added in the app run code from the tutorial In hopes it would work but it didn't, I got the same error and I could never get an error log, so I switched back to "app.run()" and when I restart apache I get an error log:

```
import flask
import settings

# Views
from main import Main
from login import Login
from remote import Remote
from music import Music    

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = settings.secret_key

# Routes
app.add_url_rule('/',
                view_func=Main.as_view('main'),
                methods=["GET"])
app.add_url_rule('/<page>/',
                 view_func=Main.as_view('page'),
                 methods=["GET"])
app.add_url_rule('/login/',
                 view_func=Login.as_view('login'),
                 methods=["GET", "POST"])
app.add_url_rule('/remote/',
                 view_func=Remote.as_view('remote'),
                 methods=['GET', 'POST'])
app.add_url_rule('/music/',
                 view_func=Music.as_view('music'),
                 methods=['GET'])

@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(error):
  return flask.render_template('404.html'), 404

#app.debug = True
app.run()

#if __name__ == '__main__':
    #"Are we in the __main__ scope? Start test server."
    #app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000,debug=True)
```

And here is the error.log file that is returned. I have read it b

```
[Sat Jun 29 11:59:23 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=5739): Target WSGI script '/home/carwyn/public_html/wsgi/learningflask.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sat Jun 29 11:59:23 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=5739): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/carwyn/public_html/wsgi/learningflask.wsgi'.
[Sat Jun 29 11:59:23 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Jun 29 11:59:23 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/carwyn/public_html/wsgi/learningflask.wsgi", line 3, in <module>
[Sat Jun 29 11:59:23 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     from app import app as application
[Sat Jun 29 11:59:23 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/carwyn/public_html/apps/learningflask/app.py", line 35, in <module>
[Sat Jun 29 11:59:23 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     app.run()
[Sat Jun 29 11:59:23 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 772, in run
[Sat Jun 29 11:59:23 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
[Sat Jun 29 11:59:23 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 710, in run_simple
[Sat Jun 29 11:59:23 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     inner()
[Sat Jun 29 11:59:23 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 692, in inner
[Sat Jun 29 11:59:23 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     passthrough_errors, ssl_context).serve_forever()
[Sat Jun 29 11:59:23 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 436, in serve_forever
[Sat Jun 29 11:59:23 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     HTTPServer.serve_forever(self)
[Sat Jun 29 11:59:23 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 225, in serve_forever
[Sat Jun 29 11:59:23 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     r, w, e = select.select([self], [], [], poll_interval)
[Sat Jun 29 11:59:23 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] error: (4, 'Interrupted system call')
```

If you need any more information then I would be happy to provide it, I would appreciate all the help I can get.

EDIT:

Here is my learningflask.wsgi file:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/carwyn/public_html/apps/learningflask')
from app import app as application
```

And here is my available-sites apache file-thing (called learningflask), it pretty much just follows the tutorial one but is set up for the tutorial application:

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>

        # ---- Configure VirtualHost Defaults ----

    ServerAdmin carwynjohnnelson@aol.com 

        DocumentRoot /home/carwyn/public_html/http/learningflask/

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/carwyn/public_html/http/learningflask/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        # ---- Configure WSGI Listener(s) ----

        WSGIDaemonProcess learningflask user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
        WSGIScriptAlias /learningflask /home/carwyn/public_html/wsgi/learningflask.wsgi 

        <Directory /home/carwyn/public_html/http/learningflask>
                WSGIProcessGroup learningflask
                WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        # ---- Configure Logging ----

    ErrorLog /home/carwyn/public_html/logs/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /home/carwyn/public_html/logs/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

SECOND EDIT:

I hope this might help, I removed the app.run and reloaded the page and I get the error. Then I looked in my previously cleared error log and get nothing. So i restarted apache and looked in my error log and I get this:

```
[Sat Jun 29 21:33:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=5908): Target WSGI script '/home/carwyn/public_html/wsgi/learningflask.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sat Jun 29 21:33:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_wsgi (pid=5908): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/carwyn/public_html/wsgi/learningflask.wsgi'.
[Sat Jun 29 21:33:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Jun 29 21:33:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/carwyn/public_html/wsgi/learningflask.wsgi", line 3, in <module>
[Sat Jun 29 21:33:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     from app import app as application
[Sat Jun 29 21:33:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/home/carwyn/public_html/apps/learningflask/app.py", line 35, in <module>
[Sat Jun 29 21:33:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     #app.run()
[Sat Jun 29 21:33:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 772, in run
[Sat Jun 29 21:33:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
[Sat Jun 29 21:33:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 710, in run_simple
[Sat Jun 29 21:33:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     inner()
[Sat Jun 29 21:33:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 692, in inner
[Sat Jun 29 21:33:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     passthrough_errors, ssl_context).serve_forever()
[Sat Jun 29 21:33:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 436, in serve_forever
[Sat Jun 29 21:33:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     HTTPServer.serve_forever(self)
[Sat Jun 29 21:33:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 225, in serve_forever
[Sat Jun 29 21:33:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1]     r, w, e = select.select([self], [], [], poll_interval)
[Sat Jun 29 21:33:19 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] error: (4, 'Interrupted system call')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be calling:

```
app.run()
```

This is starting Flask's own HTTP server within the Apache process.

There was a reason it was inside of an if() statement checking to see whether __name__ was '__main__'. That was to ensure it was only called when the script was run from command line Python interpreter. You do not want it to be run under Apache.

Comment: When I remove app.run completely I get the following error:

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

So I have no idea what is happening outside of this. Is there any more debug information I can provide?

Comment: I hope this might help, I removed the app.run and reloaded the page and I get the error. Then I looked in my previously cleared error log and get nothing. So i restarted apache and looked in my error log and I get a bunch of errors which I have added to the main post at the bottom.

Comment: Your error suggests you changed the code but didn't restart Apache properly as is same error, but getting code snippets from modified file on disk. Try doing a complete stop and start of Apache to make sure code is reloaded.

Comment: I stopped and started the server, looked in my error log and had no errors. I loaded the page and I still get the "Internal Server Error" error. I then restarted apache how i normally do it "sudo service apache2 restart" and I still get no errors in my error log but still the same normal internal server error.

I was wandering if you wanted to do a join.me session on the VM, that might help you diagnose it. Hell maybe I'll find someone who I can bounce ideas around with in the future and learn from, and improve me as a developer. :P

Comment: Remove any .pyc files (compiled byte code file), that may exist in the same directory as the source code. Just make sure you don't remove your source code files.

Comment: I tried stopping the server, deleting the .pyc files and then starting the server. No luck just the same error on the web page and no errors appearing in my error.log file. I have no idea what is going on, but I am really confused, any more ideas? EDIT: when i load the page or restart the server no .pyc files are created, is this normal?

Comment: @CarwynNelson Did you get this issue sorted?

Comment: @Graham could you help me out with a [similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26827323/404-exception-when-deploying-a-flask-application-via-mod-wsgi)?

Comment: @AnandS Hi, sorry I never got it figured out, but I thought I would leave the question here just in case any of the solutions helped other people